# djgpp compiled harbour exe does not run in pure dos

Tags: dos, exe, clipper, djgpp

I have compiled one clipper program using haarbour compiler and the c file produced was compiled using djgpp to produce final exe. This exe runs fine in console window of Windows 98.
However, when I exit to msdos prompt or try to run in pure dos, it does not give any error. But did not go further. however num lock  and cap locks responds propery. When I press ctrl+al+del it gives me message hdpmi terminated by the user. I have tried cwsdpmi instead of Hdpmi32 but the problem remains same.
There is on exe HBRUN.exe which acts as an interpreter to .hrb files produced instead of stand alone exe. When I run HBRUn in pure do,it behaved in the same fashion. But when I runit another directory where no dbf files were there, it gave me error dbf file not found ! This also works fine in console window but compiled for pure DOS.
I think there is some problem with all the exes produced using harbour and djgpp if they are big.
one simple 5-6 line program's .hrb file was run correctly in pure dos by hbrun ( Size of hbrun is about 1700 K where as my exe file size is 950 K
Can anybody shade some light ?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, you're unlikely to find any help here. I would suggest approaching the Harbour Project itself for help. They can be found [on github](http://harbour.github.io/) with [their list of developers (with email addresses!)](http://harbour.github.io/crew.html)

Answer (score 0):

Harbour is powerful.
http://harbour.github.io/

To run in pure DOS I would recommend you to try OPENWATCOM

Here is a copy of the message from Pritpal Bedi (one of the developers):

I could compile Harbour with OpenWatcom DOS.
Machine : WIndows 7 32 Bits

STEPS:

1. Downloaded: http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/openwatcom/open-watcom-c-dos-1.9.exe
2. Installed in C:\WATCOM. Follow all default options when installing except making changes to AUTOEXEC.bat and CONFIG.sys.
   WATCOM will save these two files with .DOS as extention.
3. Copy C:\Watcom\autoexec.dos C:\Watcom\m.bat
4. Redefine PATH statement as : SET PATH=C:\WATCOM\BINW;C:\Harbour\bin\dos\watcom;%PATH%
5. Keep all other SETs intact.
6. CD to C:\Harbour
7. Execute C:\Watcom\m.bat
8. Execute DOS-MAKE     [ Do Not use "install" option, it will pollute your existing environment ]
9. Harbour binaries will be deposited in C:\Harbour\bin\dos\watcom

NOTE [ And it is strange ] that steps 7 and 8 will have to be repeated for few times 
         as console window from where you are initiating it will disappear, but do not worry,
         it seems to be an issue with memory.

1. CD to harbour\tests
2. Issue : hbmk2 hello -workdir= -run
    It appears long command line do not go through, so we have to shorten the path and hence command line length.
3. Be cheerful as you will see "Hello World" printed in current console.

Pritpal Bedi